# Getting the child div length using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

what is wrong with this code

```
   var divlenght=$("#+"$("#meetingstopright").children().children().attr('id'))> div").length;
```

I am trying to find the number of child div at one level.

Comment: `var divlenght = $("#meetingstopright").children().children().find('div').length`

Comment: How does your HTML markup looks like and what are you trying to get ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plus sign shouldn't be outside the quotation marks? to concatenate string? like this:

```
$("#"+
```

and after the id attr i think you should concatenate again, like:

```
attr('id'))+" > div")
```

You could break the proccess into some small stuff like the code down here, until you find the problem

```
console.log($("#meetingstopright"))
console.log($("#meetingstopright").children())
console.log($("#meetingstopright").children().children())
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your HTML markup, It is hard to tell what you are trying to achieve. But generally, it is better to give a css class name to your specific div in your HTML markup so that you can use that css class name in your jQuery selection instead of doing chained `children` calls

```
<div id="meetingstopright">
   <div class="child">
       <div class="child3" id="id16">
          <div class="meetingItem">Item 1</div>
          <div class="meetingItem">Item 2</div>
          <div class="meetingItem">Item 2</div>
       </div>       
   </div>
 </div>
```

And to get the count of the Item div's, You can use `find` method with the css class name. `find` method will go deeper into the hierarchy and get it.

```
var meetingcount = $("#meetingstopright").find("div.meetingItem").length;
```